# Как передать props в mixin?

Tags: vue.js

Я использую webpack и однофайловые компоненты, хочу расширить компонент из плагина. Делаю так:

```
import BImgLaze from 'bootstrap-vue/src/components/image/img-lazy'
export default {
  name: "b-img-lazy-ex",
  extend: BImgLaze,
}
```

Использую компонент:

```
<b-img-lazy-ex :src="require('./assets/img/' + img.filename)" center fluid blank-color="#000"/>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что src и другие атрибуты не передаются в компонент от которого я расширился.

Comment: не extend, а extends

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "src"

found in

---> <BImgLazyEx> at src/b-img-lazy-ex.vue... (496 recursive calls)
       <ScGallery> at src/sc-gallery.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>

Comment: props унаследовалось и просит чтобы вы объявили src

Comment: И как это сделать? Просто указать src в props унаследованного компонента не работает.